Programmatically Generate Bitbucket HTTP Access Token Using Existing Access Token
As the title states, is it possible to programmatically generate an HTTP access token on Bitbucket server from an existing access token, e.g. via their REST API?
From reading their documentation, it only seems possible via client IDs and client secrets; however, I'm looking to use an authentication value that I can routinely rotate.
Is this possible in BitBucket server?

"I'm looking to use an authentication value that I can routinely rotate" Might be a silly question, but could you not rotate the client secret to achieve this?

@esqew Unfortunately, no. I don't have access to the client ID and client secret for this BitBucket server.

From where are you getting the "existing access token"; i.e., what endpoint? What kind of HTTP Access Token are you looking to generate? There are several kinds you could generate using the API, so long as the "existing access token" in question has the proper authorization to do so.

@esqew Currently using personal access tokens that I manually generate from the UI. Seems there do exist endpoints for creating new personal access tokens - though it appears that you cannot use a personal access token to create a new personal access token.
